# Echo input from users only if it exists or is of desired value

Tags: php

I am building a Order form for a Client's website. One of the pages lets users choose Vehicle Spareparts by entering the quantity beside each part. I have achieved this by writing the following code

```
<input class="qty" type="number" name="oil-pump" min="0" max="100">
```

The above input attribute is added several times besides each sparepart type while changing just the *name* value. On clicking Submit, the user is taken to a review page with details on the spareparts ordered.

I presently have the following code in review page:

```
<?php
echo 'Engine Bearings: ' . $_POST['eng-bearings'];
echo 'Cylinder Heads: ' . $_POST['cyl-heads'];
echo 'Cam and Valve Train: ' . $_POST['cam-valve-train'];
echo 'Oil Pump: ' . $_POST['oil-pump'];
echo 'Oil Caps and Pipes: ' . $_POST['oil-caps-pipes'];
?>
```

This works well if the user has entered a value in every field. If he doesn't, then the review page has just the echo text without any quantity. Also, I don't want the quantity to apppear if the user has entered 0.

I can't figure out how to use isset() with null and OR statements to not echo text when the value entered is 0 or left blank.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: You don't need `isset()`, you need `empty()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect opportunity for a function:

```
function print_user_input($title, $queryVar) {
    if (isset($_POST[$queryVar]) && !empty($_POST[$queryVar])) {
        echo $title . ': ' . $_POST[$queryVar];
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
print_user_input('Engine Bearings', 'eng-bearings');
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. It echos text only when the input field is not empty or 0. But, can you please explain how the code works? I don't see anywhere in your function reference to 0. Thanks!

Comment: That would be the [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function at work. If you go to the documentation page you will see the list of things that php considers "empty" and 0 is one of those things.

Comment: Glad I learned something new. Thanks for helping me fix this issue. I have multiple spareparts with quantity boxes on my page. Using your code is able to echo text when the input is not empty of 0. I found that all the text was getting echoed on the same line. So, added a line break:

`echo $title . ': ' . $_POST[$queryVar] . "<br/>";`

Hope this helps someone following along.

Answer (score 1):

Echo the value conditionally. If the target data is empty, echo an empty string:

```
echo empty($_POST['eng-bearings']) ? '': 'Engine Bearings: ' . $_POST['eng-bearings'];
```

Repeat for the other post values. Information about the ternary operator (`<conditional> ? <value1> : <value2>`) is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-137).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if its set & that its not empty before printing it on a screen.

```
<?php
if (! empty($_POST['eng-bearings'])) {
   echo 'Engine Bearings: ' . $_POST['eng-bearings'];
} else {
   // whatever you wanna do here in case eng-bearings is not set or its empty
}

// Do same for other $_POST values ...
?>
```